# Ошибка в контроллере

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Суть проблемы такая: при написании контроллера, столкнулся с его некорректной работой - он возвращает ошибку, подскажите пожалуйста почему появляется данная ошибка и как ее исправить. Заранее благодарю.

**Ошибка:** *org.springframework.web.bind.UnsatisfiedServletRequestParameterException: Parameter conditions "id" not met for actual request parameters*

**Код контроллера:**

```
package ru.vegd.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import ru.vegd.service.NewsService;

import java.sql.SQLException;

@Controller
public class NewsReadController {

    @Autowired
    NewsService newsService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/news/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, params = {"id"})
    public String singleNews( @RequestParam(name="id", required = true) Long id, Model model) throws SQLException {
        System.out.println(id);
        model.addAttribute("news", newsService.read(id));
        return "news/readOne";
    }

}
```

**readOne.html:**

```
<style type="text/css">
   table {
    border-spacing: 0 10px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
th {
padding: 10px 20px;
background: #56433D;
color: #F9C941;
border-right: 2px solid;
font-size: 0.9em;
}
td {
vertical-align: middle;
padding: 10px;
font-size: 14px;
text-align: center;
border-top: 2px solid #56433D;
border-bottom: 2px solid #56433D;
border-right: 2px solid #56433D;
}
td:first-child {
border-left: 2px solid #56433D;
}
td:nth-child(2){
text-align: left;
}
td:nth-child(4){
font-size: 20px;
text-align: left;
padding: 10px;
font-size: 14px;
}

</style>

<table xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th> ID </th>
        <th> Author </th>
        <th> Title </th>
        <th> News </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><span th:text="${news.news_id}"> ID </span></td>
        <td><span th:text="${news.author_id}"> Author </span></td>
        <td><span th:text="${news.tittle}"> Tittle </span></td>
        <td><span th:text="${news.news_text}"> News </span></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Ссылка: http://localhost:8080/news/2**

Comment: А какая точная ссылка, по которой осуществляется запрос?  Там что то с параметром id не то, возможно передается тип отличный от long.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/news/2

Comment: Попробуйте убрать из аннотации @RequestMapping параметр params = {"id"}, он предназначен для фильтрации по какому то конкретному значению ид, а не для описания ссылки.

Comment: Выдало org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required Long parameter 'id' is not present

Comment: Над методом аннотация: `@GetMapping("/news/{id}")`. И принимаете параметр с помощью аннотации @PathVariable: `singleNews(@PathVariable Long id) {...}`

Comment: @RequestParam для query параметров, то есть ссылка должна была бы быть `http://localhost:8080/news?id=2`

Comment: Заработало, спасибо. Офорите как ответ not Programmer. Ссылка http://localhost:8080/news?id=2 не работает почему то, для корректной работы нужна http://localhost:8080/news/2.
tsybun_na Спасибо за помощь тоже.

Comment: странно что с @RequestMapping не заработало

Comment: да я сам чего-то не врубаюсь, если делать через @PathVariable, то приложение не работает, возвращается вместо html страницы просто путь к ней.